# Understanding Ruby messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

To provide some background; I've been learning Ruby for the passed few months (have read most of Well-Grounded-Rubyist, completed Poignant ruby guide, and planning on reading Eloquent ruby afterwards) I have grasped most concepts i.e Objects, the Ruby kernel (fundamentals), scope, loops and so forth, however, I am confused when it comes to sending messages/methods to code.

Let's use this line of code as an example: `toolkit   = Toolkit.get_default_toolkit`

Now toolkit is the variable for the Toolkit object and get_default_toolkit is the method/message. What I find ambiguous in most code is that the method/message isn't defined anywhere. So my question is, is there a list of Kernal messages/methods that we (rubyists) can study that are used at a fundamental level?

Or do these methods just have large scope, and are defined somewhere else within the program?

Answer (score 6):

The methods are defined in the class definition, as they are with virtually every language. `get_default_toolkit` isn't some low-level method that you'll have to hunt through core Ruby classes to find, it's part of class `Toolkit` and it'll be defined where ever that class is defined.

There *are* such methods, like those defined in `Kernel` or `Object`, but `get_default_toolkit` isn't one of them.

For any given method, you can figure out which class it was defined in by calling `object.method('method_name').owner`, or find out where it was defined (file/line number) by calling `.source_location`.

> Now toolkit is the variable for the Toolkit object

The better way of wording this is that `toolkit` is a variable, and `Toolkit` is a class, and `toolkit` now contains a new *instance* of the `Toolkit` class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find what method calls are available for an object or class you can call .methods on it

e.g.

```
pp String.methods.sort

thing = Array.new
pp thing.methods.sort
```

I like to call them with pp and sort so they are printed in a readable manner